# ANDROID java.lang.IllegalArgumentException declares multiple JSON fields named mLifecycleRegistry проблема с методом toJson()

Tags: java, android, json

Я хочу запихнуть класс NoteContentItems с ArrayList в строку с помощью метода toJson(), чтобы потом передать в Intent. Столкнулся с ошибкой, её можно увидеть ниже, как код класса NoteContentItems и вызов toJson(). Как я понял не абы какой класс можно запихнуть в toJson(). Если кто-то в этом понимает - помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

ОШИБКА:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mainandroidproject, PID: 11291
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.mainandroidproject.NewNote declares multiple JSON fields named mLifecycleRegistry
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
        at com.example.mainandroidproject.NewNote.returnNewNoteData(NewNote.java:368)
        at com.example.mainandroidproject.NewNote.access$200(NewNote.java:47)
        at com.example.mainandroidproject.NewNote$1.onClick(NewNote.java:147)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7161)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7138)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:811)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27419)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

NoteContentItems КЛАСС:

```
public class NoteContentItems {

    private ArrayList<View> items;

    public NoteContentItems() {
        items = new ArrayList<View>();
    }
    public void addItem(View itemInput) {
        items.add(itemInput);
    }
}
```

Место, где я пытаюсь применить toJson():

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("newNoteTitle",newNoteTitle);
        intent.putExtra("newNoteText",newNoteText);

        Gson jsonSave = new Gson();
        NoteContentItems noteContentItem = new NoteContentItems();
        View view = new View(NewNote.this);
        noteContentItem.addItem(view);
        String someElementString = jsonSave.toJson(noteContentItem);
        intent.putExtra("someElement",someElementString);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка выглядит так:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.mainandroidproject.NewNote declares multiple JSON fields named mLifecycleRegistry
```

если дословно:

```
класс com.example.mainandroidproject.NewNote имеет несколько объявленных полей с названием mLifecycleRegistry
```

поэтому проверяйте класс `NewNote` на наличие одинаково названных полей. Посмотрите приходящий json если вы на него не имеете влияния, и вероятнее всего там будут разные поля.